# git post-receive hook never executes

Tags: git, hook

For some reason my post-received hook never executes. It's a simple two liner diagnostic script: echo "test" && touch /tmp/test. When I do `git push origin master` nothing happens. Does any-one know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you ensured that the script is executable (and if it's a shell script, properly formatted with a valid `#!interpreter` line)? This is the source of 99% of the "my post-receive hook doesn't work" complaints :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using http, know that HTTP does not support hooks and you could ssh:/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the script file itself is actually executable.

`chmod ug+x .git/hooks/post-receive`